# NUFFT/FFT interpretation

Tags: fft, lowpass-filter

I know this has been covered thousands of times on the internet, but I'm still struggling with it.

My end goal is to cancel out the noise in an Inertial Measurement Unit chip readings so I can double-integrate acceleration to get reasonably accurate vertical displacement (of a buoy bobbing on ocean wave swells).  I believe I've already corrected for orientation, so my acceleration values are of vertical movement.

I have 60 seconds of acceleration samples (in m/s^2) of the IMU at rest.  My samples are at uneven time spacing (~110ms apart, but not precisely) so I'm using [this matlab demo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.nufft.html) to start from and adding my own data.

The starting point for the demo plots `f = (0:n-1)/n` but that doesn't really seem to make sense for my output.  It makes more sense to me to do something like this: `f = (-(n-1)/2:(n-1)/2)/n;` which is symmetrical about 0.

I also can't figure out the appropriate scale for the X-axis values.  I think I want it to be Hertz, and to help me figure that out I added a synthetic 0.5Hz cosine wave `check_signal = 2.0 * Math.cos((t * 2.0 * Math.PI) / (1.0 / 0.5));` to each acceleration sample so that I could maybe see that spike and verify that it indicates a strong "0.5 Hz" component.  But after several experiments, I'm not seeing it.

I also seem to need to multiply my times by 1000 to have them be integers(?), or the output graph is less sensible.

```
t = [0.111 0.216 0.326 0.437 0.546 0.656 0.766 0.876 0.986 1.097 1.207 1.318 1.4280000000000002 1.5380000000000003 1.6490000000000002 1.7590000000000003 1.8700000000000003 1.9760000000000004 2.0900000000000003 2.2010000000000005 2.3100000000000005 2.4190000000000005 2.5260000000000007 2.6360000000000006 2.7460000000000004 2.8560000000000003 2.966 3.0770000000000004 3.1870000000000003 3.297 3.4080000000000004 3.5180000000000002 3.628 3.738 3.849 3.9600000000000004 4.07 4.181 4.2860000000000005 4.399000000000001 4.508000000000001 4.6160000000000005 4.726000000000001 4.836000000000001 4.9460000000000015 5.056000000000002 5.167000000000002 5.277000000000002 5.388000000000002 5.498000000000002 5.608000000000002 5.719000000000002 5.829000000000002 5.940000000000002 6.046000000000002 6.160000000000002 6.271000000000002 6.380000000000002 6.489000000000002 6.596000000000002 6.706000000000002 6.8160000000000025 6.926000000000003 7.036000000000003 7.147000000000003 7.257000000000003 7.3670000000000035 7.478000000000003 7.588000000000004 7.699000000000003 7.808000000000003 7.919000000000003 8.030000000000003 8.140000000000002 8.251000000000003 8.356000000000003 8.466000000000003 8.576000000000002 8.686000000000002 8.796000000000001 8.906 9.016 9.127 9.237 9.347 9.458 9.568 9.679 9.789 9.899 10.01 10.116 10.231 10.34 10.448 10.556000000000001 10.666 10.776 10.886 10.995999999999999 11.105999999999998 11.216999999999999 11.326999999999998 11.437999999999999 11.547999999999998 11.658999999999999 11.768999999999998 11.875999999999998 11.989999999999998 12.099999999999998 12.210999999999999 12.319999999999999 12.425999999999998 12.535999999999998 12.645999999999997 12.755999999999997 12.865999999999996 12.975999999999996 13.085999999999995 13.196999999999996 13.306999999999995 13.417999999999996 13.527999999999995 13.637999999999995 13.748999999999995 13.859999999999996 13.969999999999995 14.079999999999995 14.185999999999995 14.296999999999995 14.407999999999996 14.515999999999996 14.625999999999996 14.735999999999995 14.845999999999995 14.955999999999994 15.066999999999995 15.176999999999994 15.287999999999995 15.397999999999994 15.507999999999994 15.618999999999994 15.728999999999994 15.839999999999995 15.945999999999994 16.059999999999995 16.170999999999996 16.279999999999998 16.387999999999998 16.496 16.605999999999998 16.723999999999997 16.825999999999997 16.935999999999996 17.046999999999997 17.156999999999996 17.267999999999997 17.377999999999997 17.487999999999996 17.598999999999997 17.706999999999997 17.819999999999997 17.929999999999996 18.039999999999996 18.150999999999996 18.255999999999997 18.365999999999996 18.475999999999996 18.585999999999995 18.695999999999994 18.805999999999994 18.915999999999993 19.026999999999994 19.136999999999993 19.247999999999994 19.357999999999993 19.467999999999993 19.578999999999994 19.688999999999993 19.799999999999994 19.909999999999993 20.015999999999995 20.127999999999993 20.237999999999992 20.345999999999993 20.455999999999992 20.565999999999992 20.67599999999999 20.78599999999999 20.89599999999999 21.00699999999999 21.11699999999999 21.22799999999999 21.33799999999999 21.44799999999999 21.55899999999999 21.66999999999999 21.775999999999993 21.889999999999993 22.000999999999994 22.109999999999996 22.218999999999998 22.325999999999997 22.435999999999996 22.545999999999996 22.655999999999995 22.765999999999995 22.876999999999995 22.986999999999995 23.096999999999994 23.207999999999995 23.317999999999994 23.427999999999994 23.536999999999995 23.648999999999994 23.759999999999994 23.869999999999994 23.980999999999995 24.085999999999995 24.197999999999993 24.305999999999994 24.415999999999993 24.525999999999993 24.635999999999992 24.74599999999999 24.85599999999999 24.96699999999999 25.07699999999999 25.18799999999999 25.29799999999999 25.40799999999999 25.51899999999999 25.62899999999999 25.73999999999999 25.845999999999993 25.958999999999993 26.069999999999993 26.178999999999995 26.286999999999995 26.395999999999997 26.505999999999997 26.615999999999996 26.725999999999996 26.835999999999995 26.946999999999996 27.056999999999995 27.167999999999996 27.277999999999995 27.387999999999995 27.498999999999995 27.606999999999996 27.722999999999995 27.829999999999995 27.939999999999994 28.049999999999994 28.155999999999995 28.265999999999995 28.375999999999994 28.485999999999994 28.595999999999993 28.705999999999992 28.816999999999993 28.926999999999992 29.036999999999992 29.147999999999993 29.257999999999992 29.36799999999999 29.478999999999992 29.58899999999999 29.699999999999992 29.80999999999999 29.915999999999993 30.028999999999993 30.137999999999995 30.246999999999996 30.355999999999998 30.465999999999998 30.575999999999997 30.685999999999996 30.796999999999997 30.906999999999996 31.017999999999997 31.127999999999997 31.237999999999996 31.348999999999997 31.458999999999996 31.569999999999997 31.676 31.79 31.901 32.009 32.118 32.226 32.336 32.446 32.556 32.666 32.776999999999994 32.88699999999999 32.99699999999999 33.10799999999999 33.21799999999999 33.328999999999986 33.43699999999998 33.548999999999985 33.65999999999998 33.76999999999998 33.88099999999998 33.985999999999976 34.095999999999975 34.205999999999975 34.315999999999974 34.42599999999997 34.53599999999997 34.64599999999997 34.75699999999997 34.86699999999997 34.977999999999966 35.087999999999965 35.197999999999965 35.30899999999996 35.41899999999996 35.52999999999996 35.63999999999996 35.74599999999996 35.85999999999996 35.969999999999956 36.07799999999995 36.18599999999995 36.29599999999995 36.40599999999995 36.51599999999995 36.62599999999995 36.736999999999945 36.846999999999944 36.95799999999994 37.06799999999994 37.17799999999994 37.28899999999994 37.39899999999994 37.505999999999936 37.61999999999993 37.72999999999993 37.83999999999993 37.94999999999993 38.05599999999993 38.16599999999993 38.27599999999993 38.38599999999993 38.49599999999993 38.60699999999993 38.71699999999993 38.82699999999993 38.937999999999924 39.047999999999924 39.15899999999992 39.26799999999992 39.37899999999992 39.48999999999992 39.599999999999916 39.71099999999991 39.816999999999915 39.92599999999992 40.035999999999916 40.145999999999916 40.255999999999915 40.365999999999914 40.475999999999914 40.58699999999991 40.69699999999991 40.80799999999991 40.91799999999991 41.027999999999906 41.1389999999999 41.2489999999999 41.3599999999999 41.4699999999999 41.5759999999999 41.6909999999999 41.7989999999999 41.9079999999999 42.0159999999999 42.1259999999999 42.2359999999999 42.3459999999999 42.4559999999999 42.566999999999894 42.67699999999989 42.78699999999989 42.89799999999989 43.00799999999989 43.118999999999886 43.228999999999886 43.335999999999885 43.44999999999988 43.55999999999988 43.67099999999988 43.77999999999988 43.88599999999988 43.99599999999988 44.10599999999988 44.21599999999988 44.32599999999988 44.43599999999988 44.546999999999876 44.656999999999876 44.76799999999987 44.87799999999987 44.98799999999987 45.09799999999987 45.20899999999987 45.31899999999987 45.429999999999865 45.539999999999864 45.645999999999866 45.75799999999987 45.86799999999987 45.975999999999864 46.08599999999986 46.19599999999986 46.30599999999986 46.41599999999986 46.52699999999986 46.63699999999986 46.747999999999855 46.857999999999855 46.967999999999854 47.07899999999985 47.18899999999985 47.29999999999985 47.40599999999985 47.51999999999985 47.630999999999844 47.739999999999846 47.84799999999984 47.95599999999984 48.06599999999984 48.17599999999984 48.28599999999984 48.39599999999984 48.506999999999834 48.616999999999834 48.72799999999983 48.83799999999983 48.94799999999983 49.05899999999983 49.165999999999826 49.278999999999826 49.38999999999982 49.49999999999982 49.61099999999982 49.715999999999816 49.831999999999816 49.935999999999815 50.045999999999815 50.155999999999814 50.26599999999981 50.37599999999981 50.48699999999981 50.59699999999981 50.70799999999981 50.817999999999806 50.927999999999805 51.0389999999998 51.1489999999998 51.2599999999998 51.3699999999998 51.4759999999998 51.5889999999998 51.6999999999998 51.807999999999794 51.91599999999979 52.02599999999979 52.13599999999979 52.24599999999979 52.35599999999979 52.466999999999786 52.576999999999785 52.686999999999784 52.79799999999978 52.90799999999978 53.01899999999978 53.12899999999978 53.23599999999978 53.349999999999774 53.45999999999977 53.57099999999977 53.67899999999977 53.78599999999977 53.895999999999766 54.005999999999766 54.115999999999765 54.225999999999765 54.335999999999764 54.44699999999976 54.55699999999976 54.66799999999976 54.77799999999976 54.88799999999976 54.997999999999756 55.10899999999975 55.21999999999975 55.32999999999975 55.44099999999975 55.545999999999744 55.65899999999974 55.767999999999745 55.87599999999974 55.98599999999974 56.09599999999974 56.20599999999974 56.31599999999974 56.42699999999974 56.536999999999736 56.64799999999973 56.75799999999973 56.86799999999973 56.97899999999973 57.08899999999973 57.199999999999726 57.30599999999973 57.419999999999725 57.53099999999972 57.63999999999972 57.74799999999972 57.85599999999972 57.96599999999972 58.075999999999716 58.185999999999716 58.295999999999715 58.40699999999971 58.51699999999971 58.62699999999971 58.73799999999971 58.84799999999971 58.958999999999705 59.06799999999971 59.178999999999704 59.2899999999997 59.3999999999997 59.5109999999997 59.615999999999694 59.725999999999694 59.83599999999969 59.94599999999969 60.05599999999969]
X = [1.8693669021726393 1.567987603134047 1.0493406852414189 0.39326138923084003 -0.28910356510450447 -0.9430408643306653 -1.4848405454774782 -1.8507054136689158 -1.9980658693562494 -1.8897883011347871 -1.5923336933620313 -1.0819775042537518 -0.46878052189876124 0.25653432018974026 0.9201771688836917 1.4533529309738067 1.8357742513679631 2.004299800521228 1.9103303713538857 1.6137918464927992 1.123625755704259 0.5129040973369916 -0.16318122313631853 -0.819310161986571 -1.3971468379869472 -1.799892503132743 -1.988877580793998 -1.9420439116374617 -1.6646825476813265 -1.1816026794167094 -0.5603325249399492 0.12355906896404827 0.7832883336744038 1.3798597574448372 1.7772537527566765 1.9831474026289557 1.9618155238774948 1.6763808243208649 1.2455755609762242 0.613749593376827 -0.040278190886677834 -0.6950347574265046 -1.3155474506017597 -1.7409185093390542 -1.9807301902979977 -1.969944669058409 -1.720755660506034 -1.2895909772551768 -0.6787738463490243 -0.01149428793110781 0.6748040890459824 1.2789004188575308 1.716103162548551 1.95350050145738 1.9786112372053009 1.7623193600877238 1.3284261246674265 0.73489210536935 0.06855028274893474 -0.5948991631540766 -1.2064100833780604 -1.6650740800842907 -1.9472790219642562 -1.9772406210400146 -1.8007482966496164 -1.381967937910402 -0.81210051533238 -0.1405590514287942 0.5442808710346737 1.1810035080510362 1.647055195256864 1.9358592006577358 1.9997479292061586 1.808838104932033 1.4092127078847108 0.8839375333018458 0.21240630855050513 -0.47327399404746334 -1.1032917412568661 -1.603674969741757 -1.9137001031176606 -1.9866859132120351 -1.8429136816429963 -1.4713167215620309 -0.9241945020819893 -0.2634047181845686 0.4242792198441053 1.067690241474376 1.586157223980879 1.9101440382015404 1.9990131207314634 1.878639884913226 1.505500597806763 0.9616093482034371 0.33389833038977423 -0.35112811795055954 -0.9772232106789817 -1.5254260220228908 -1.8833567734963843 -2.011722088407632 -1.9009241503596148 -1.533010025374161 -1.0339969802763258 -0.3771169361017239 0.2993691782415033 0.9677026052895087 1.5065715978067595 1.849603413668912 2.007903120731463 1.9021130325903113 1.575359223980891 1.0708375899580054 0.47048485335320095 -0.23515376974694988 -0.8747284620777841 -1.4411690497757939 -1.8356401748069966 -1.9846118005212257 -1.9185473565800293 -1.6185194541410344 -1.1316236989438757 -0.5081944513667881 0.19566539310145448 0.8301894568235766 1.4086817078847018 1.8074801049320246 1.9908479292061576 1.936625322257271 1.6678808672263647 1.2007496794167345 0.5894505249399858 -0.10238663635951867 -0.7714439845547674 -1.3495836162420227 -1.7707386226648905 -1.9698598513932974 -1.967197679661452 -1.708937800526651 -1.2357192261806986 -0.6294320393106528 0.049984190886636075 0.7279645237831354 1.3173531246674064 1.7706683600877073 1.9707481902979906 1.9648505014573825 1.7193591625485611 1.27268397949739 0.6890098463490467 0.01515007976671835 -0.6540520593098655 -1.2943879231388649 -1.7088308633985791 -1.951361104768488 -1.9782376255439265 -1.76107522984602 -1.3420057348685155 -0.7382124114756232 -0.07565636533990062 0.6012572843769808 1.220295814761986 1.6891968510040196 1.950210523877489 1.98314740262896 1.7788757527566872 1.386765611625624 0.8464261494727225 0.15065361105589958 -0.5254449786407109 -1.1554214068445066 -1.6307392186508802 -1.9202412776665347 -1.991452371289188 -1.8176093647121 -1.4133653544185971 -0.8631880913619587 -0.20072342970248216 0.4904755423848112 1.1089825162042923 1.628280988749871 1.920046371353873 1.997197913212037 1.840728694731762 1.4665106924451528 0.928679156154959 0.26532358136931683 -0.4219822175397012 -1.0503492599225437 -1.5655976211531455 -1.8847556099894658 -1.9900864088739694 -1.8669602652678168 -1.5184847614722554 -0.9739592514507225 -0.32581533038982596 0.36695589712458987 1.016184831500684 1.5238030220228662 1.8814855379084325 1.9997141304037165 1.8804045379084648 1.5536579273557347 1.0291126852414294 0.40050196102884716 -0.28829756510447757 -0.9416838643306221 -1.4859225454774503 -1.8528075020381212 -1.9977912686850794 -1.8976063011348014 -1.5879807972956932 -1.0717205042537774 -0.44909252189881327 0.23221968961790265 0.8915801688836583 1.457937254842786 1.8449502513679434 1.9950911305564214 1.927171356580032 1.635370328866224 1.1451292511892088 0.5211420125798468 -0.17317322313626712 -0.8093291619865305 -1.3963408379869002 -1.7990865031327175 -1.99115962398286 -1.9420439116374784 -1.6520267983916577 -1.18652964032216 -0.5713955249400225 0.1184936427802781 0.78852544868585 1.3685432118573433 1.771268622664886 1.9731651202211173 1.9815025238775068 1.6901162113357118 1.2395615159531297 0.641611219614437 -0.03769687943077555 -0.7122827574264695 -1.3044834506017366 -1.7406435093390271 -1.9715342724579712 -1.9685702513022851 -1.729479834385682 -1.2845053063532026 -0.6911948463490694 -0.007365174971786787 0.65889482971768 1.2990209772551597 1.7314660540078706 1.9642985014573673 1.974560681190283 1.7643064528699184 1.341095153073475 0.7592821910436394 0.09791823663576327 -0.5940831631540171 -1.1961530833780107 -1.6587929053047425 -1.947910994954244 -1.996485718084685 -1.7774258483025471 -1.3779626167747443 -0.815804871427379 -0.13185119590280436 0.5516697652974237 1.1752945045848973 1.6641321485490934 1.9304872776665323 1.9900824024103754 1.8047118490822507 1.4366442045528682 0.8742315333018954 0.22320430855054582 -0.46248599404743046 -1.0836037412568262 -1.5974418002242365 -1.9166002919152374 -1.9970791002179509 -1.830757694731755 -1.46706169244514 -0.9133098686686165 -0.25771486040064673 0.4357354827930543 1.0600452599225836 1.5811160247513698 1.9129352538913509 1.9884026153005132 1.8716842249164234 1.5167238305774462 1.0051426830966053 0.3368508894254863 -0.3519441179505402 -0.9866642106789524 -1.5392000628461495 -1.8558709985944555 -1.990470174217899 -1.8679160717857575 -1.5498221203975175 -1.0243130002287737 -0.39380238923096333 0.31664356747380995 0.9626803482033156 1.4985991392608369 1.8618567862338191 2.007230869356243 1.9199760894933375 1.6055708790772427 1.1027706934686723 0.46832085335335827 -0.2265397697467892 -0.8857924620776519 -1.4449692857065703 -1.8290337805480377 -1.9955010127224346 -1.922973343172232 -1.625664328866329 -1.1293579001323695 -0.49510409733724015 0.18684862663675716 0.8515585831299046 1.3863488379867508 1.8196361049319194 1.9903079292061343 1.9394371929802852 1.6775868672265246 1.215497966115297 0.5820723336568467 -0.09024163635920104 -0.772524984554487 -1.3555688749399468 -1.773927511400941 -1.9826152621389654 -1.9545362471364682 -1.6967128721703666 -1.2307827403586549 -0.6245575933772262 0.03660487943039633 0.7359731053689569 1.322082730646987 1.740468360087513 1.9753666811902069 1.9788346690584833 1.7352234023291977 1.2924789231392164 0.7107746403829409 0.02593807976715003 -0.6599868297172684 -1.2516437423703837 -1.7118125353420186 -1.962997034886572 -1.9783854894759016 -1.746466653922487 -1.3223177348688802 -0.7221244204745884 -0.06363751815679854 0.6080519887493855 1.2304967403579063 1.6792869053044746 1.9370220219641316 1.996387621040079 1.7927410735707123 1.3873066116259962 0.8175631494732073 0.1503776110564151 -0.5395915889204441 -1.1513689087832402 -1.647065195256525 -1.9342789755247236 -1.9717632182863998 -1.8028904204428517 -1.4197314591449965 -0.8418525831307382 -0.16961062663767432 0.4827039940468134 1.129081900131656 1.614332846492411 1.9359145780345728 1.9971979132120665 1.845345479740491 1.475016234716801 0.9397431561555047 0.2847455813699274 -0.4192287808041622 -1.0557010238895643 -1.558704983866409 -1.8779642899803748 -1.9896623785666183 -1.8618667862341454 -1.5049108741287125 -0.9862706830972074 -0.31232793008120735 0.3747626291707143 1.033468000228031 1.55100848555111 1.882264773496125 1.9992910884076232 1.900108150359866 1.5555676031345347 1.0485346852420772 0.39914396102956257 -0.2853378236765008 -0.947222808823941 -1.4727352908478353 -1.855166306669028 -1.988596945281147 -1.9067746830346894 -1.5844292285004526 -1.0769533616540305 -0.4271214827939257 0.26064846712776063 0.8855164620770315 1.4490302603735095 1.8296663452414965 1.9937768005211647 1.926090356580257 1.6326785014348784 1.1548462511899007 0.521683012580634 -0.16971864428326128 -0.8344654273227289 -1.3953179395970576 -1.7940209187359957 -1.9696740339625056 -1.940076324807495 -1.6593076538100586 -1.1655995045857346 -0.5723663336574816 0.14526903905766775 0.8105702744736318 1.377994211856645 1.7762728976266278 2.000885851393164 1.9571618086511493 1.7211359635899335 1.245299560977039 0.6515932196153977 -0.04479475218395846 -0.7189667920108059 -1.3037305115051105 -1.746800909619325 -1.963114888415556 -1.956036156264966 -1.724976402329528 -1.2688949579032116 -0.6790988404916468 0.018605999998875876 0.6728622157818928 1.2650887225804823 1.7380938343850891 1.9588941047682609 1.987776237205469 1.7643064528704495 1.3416361530743326 0.7590071910447093 0.08056670395823419 -0.6111428124813997 -1.2155955953882365 -1.6818891645956777 -1.938796745572882 -1.985283101493798 -1.7856727562480144 -1.3696352118583255 -0.7951117812707489 -0.15066361105710505 0.5505887652962849 1.1644965045839157 1.6556891952561001 1.9310282776662009 1.9933318560681677 1.819935941370537 1.4512949660446164 0.8734155333030889 0.20643289050221605 -0.46967059208251194 -1.088022957472252 -1.6100747714214239 -1.9281175780343593 -1.9956321305565068 -1.8374545431873903 -1.4750262347173067 -0.909072999480392 -0.2506664671300476 0.4416001855790616 1.0663432414731349 1.564781621152242 1.8950026099890094 1.9996447047616461 1.8686578849137514 1.5267058305784038 0.9851786830979085 0.34199424565775965 -0.3672935805269099 -0.9980814032701796 -1.5348840136177062 -1.8777437153072174 -2.000511521712265 -1.8841566014181022 -1.5418424855525794 -0.9992118315020885 -0.35996489712622165 0.29718656510290153 0.9585376052880896 1.4918722908472988 1.859860413668287 1.997249869356177 1.909453089493774 1.5853318790781286 1.1033106934699028 0.4543864312948977 -0.2322306896162361 -0.8975824321785302 -1.449582260372915 -1.830482345241149 -1.9972720829147692 -1.9226068435781771 -1.6175029887509138 -1.135158251190608 -0.4965737743313756 0.2049929878430683 0.8507425831285497 1.4052999395964438 1.7783065031319716 1.9980315807938045 1.954326465829775 1.666258867227335 1.2057919661164747 0.5765992720312728 -0.09705737951571908 -0.7677964932610233 -1.3618047574434649 -1.7681898976262311 -1.9723691202208835 -1.9445542471367798 -1.6925652113366823 -1.2171901073074465 -0.618309988751686 0.06882528274704386 0.7120077574246894 1.303116450600292 1.7390105093381023 1.960215190297672 1.9790996690587555];
Y = nufft(X,1000*t);

n = length(t);
f = (-(n-1)/2:(n-1)/2)/n;
plot(f,abs(Y))
```

Most raw acceleration samples of the IMU at rest are like 0.01 m/s^2 or less, so I don't know why my 2.0 m/s^2 isn't showing up stronger.  I don't know why I seems to need to shift the graph to be symmetrical about 0 vs the demo.  I don't know how to fix the numerical x-axis scale.  I'm not sure that I do need integers for t or how to correctly account for the 1000x dilation if so.  Too many unknowns.  Can you please help me figure this out?

I would ultimately expect to get a graph that shows a strong spike at 0.5Hz.  Once that's sorted out, I can remove the fake signal and get the noise profile and hopefully make a lowpass filter for that (a task which will also be brand new to me).

[image: MatLab NUFFT Demo]

Comment: It seems that there are many questions in your question. Could you please edit your question so that it includes only 1? You can ask your other questions in separate posts.